# spark worker is not able to connect to master

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to deploy a Spark application using a standalone cluster manager on windows 10 ,both the master and worker are on the local machine, the master is ALIVE  but I have a problem, the worker can not connect to the master even I'm sure that the master ip address I'm trying to connect is correct
I'm using \bin>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker masterIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set SPARK_MASTER_IP=localhost and set SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost